# Dropdown remove blank item from list

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu, haml

I use this in haml to make a dropdown. I want to have the blank item before clicking (default nothing selected) as it is, but I want to remove the blank item from the list as it's nothing to select again! Is it possible?

```
- sort_options = [{text: "Text0", id: 0}, {text: "Text1", id: 1}, {text: "", id: 2}]
= select_tag id='dropdown_sorter_tag', options_for_select(sort_options.collect{ |k| [k[:text], k[:id]] }, sort_options.collect{ |k| [k[:text], k[:id]] }[2])
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

hmm, It's difficult specification

How is this code?

HTML

```
  <% sort_options = [{text: "Text0", id: 0}, {text: "Text1", id: 1}] %>
  <%= select_tag id='dropdown_sorter_tag', options_for_select(sort_options.collect{ |k| [k[:text], k[:id]] }, sort_options.collect{ |k| [k[:text], k[:id]] }[2]), include_blank: true %>
```

js(ES6)

```
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#dropdown_sorter_tag')

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  if (!selectElement.value) {
    return
  }
  const options = selectElement.querySelectorAll('option')
  for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
    if (options[i].value) {
      continue
    }
    options[i].remove()
  }
})
```

Comment: Its good that it will be be deleted after an item was selected. But at the first open, the blank item ist still in the list.

Comment: oops, I misunderstood.